# In a multimonitor environment how do I set the Start to show on a chosen screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8

I have recently bought online and upgraded my Windows 7 Pro to Windows 8 Pro, and of course, during the first days, we try as much to understand what screen has what menus as it's not perceptive, not even in the new Surface tablet as well trying out some settings...

Making my story short, I did something with the mouse (not setting, some drag or weird gesture) that **the Start menu started to appear in the left screen** - I have 3 screens.

> How do I move it **to the center screen** again?

Can't find any help online or any setting around (not even in Windows 8 help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20151122031120/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/05/21/enhancing-windows-8-for-multiple-monitors.aspx) on the Windows 8 MSDN Blog you can invoke the start screen on any monitor by using its hot corner.

> There are several ways that you can launch and move an app:
>
> - **Start.** You can bring up Start on any monitor by moving your mouse to the bottom-left corner, or via the Start charm that you can invoke from the top and bottom-right corners of any monitor. Pressing the Windows key launches Start on the last monitor where Start or a Metro style app appeared.

There doesn't seem to be a way to fix the current setting to avoid accidentally moving the start screen like you did.

Comment: got it! thanks... but it's hard to get the hot corner icon up :-/

Comment: You should have a small corner where the cursor cannot cross monitor boundaries. You should be able to access it by moving the mouse along the lower edge.

Comment: yes, but needs to be reaaallly gentle, otherwise, we're in the next screen ... getting hard to do a simple thing on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>**Page** Up</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>**Page** Down</kbd> to move the Start Screen (and all Modern UI apps) to a different monitor.

Comment: doesnt work on my Windows 8 Pro (when Start up menu is onscreen), and you wanted to say Windows + Left/Right arrow as Up and Down is to minimize/Normal/Maximize :)

Comment: @balexandre: Windows + **Page** Up, not Windows + Up.  I've tried it; it does work.